# how to check if enough time has passed since last loop?

Tags: python

I want the loop to happen every 1 second, but don't want to use time.sleep()

Right now, I'm stuck here:

```
    while True:
        try:
            if unix_time_ms - time_prior >= 1000 is False:
                raise ValueError()
        except:
            continue
        break
```

where unix_time_ms is current unix time in ms, and time_prior is the unix time of last loop in ms.

It's not working but I'm not really sure where I made the mistake.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you intend the loop to do in that 1 second?

Comment: Why don't you want to use sleep? It's the right tool here: do stuff, measure time elapsed, sleep for the remainder of the second.

Comment: Zoso / i want it to stay within the "try/except" section

Comment: @memory942 Not using `time.sleep()` will result in a busy while-loop that does nothing but just takes up CPU cycles. I don't really understand why you would want such a construct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `time.time()` like below:

```
import time

loop_time = time.time()
while True:
    if time.time() - loop_time > 1:
        loop_time = time.time()
        print('Hello World')
    else:
        continue
```

But I would strongly recommend you to use `time.sleep()`:

```
import time

while True:
    print('Hello World')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: That's not the right way to use `sleep` here. Timestamp the start of the loop, and only sleep for `1 - now + start`

Answer (score -1):

Make sure You are using time in millisecond, can do it by time.time()*1000, also just
remove `is False` from your condition